# XSLT Transformation XML elements

Tags: xml, xslt

Example input XML:

```
<offers>
    <o id="2801" url="https://url/" price="169.14" avail="1" weight="1"
       stock="160" basket="1">
        <cat><![CDATA[Perfumy męskie]]></cat>
        <name><![CDATA[4711, 4711, woda kolońska, 800 ml]]></name>
        <imgs>
            <main url="https://teewy.pl/wp-content/uploads "/>
        </imgs>
    </o>
</offers>
```

I saw this a while back, but I can't find the topic now, so maybe someone can help me. I saw an xsl code that converted xml to output using a few lines of xslt without knowing the names of XML elements to output like:

```
`<offers>
<o>
<id>2801</id>
<url>https://url/</url>
....
</o>
</offers>`
```

can anyone give me a tip how to do?

Comment: You can use an instruction like `xsl:for-each select="@*"` to create an **element** for each **attribute** of the context node. Assuming that's what you mean - the question is  too vague.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <!-- Default copy template for nodes-->
  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- Default template for all atributes creating elements-->
  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Downvoted because?